# Error when attempting to modify lmer fixed effect: could not find function "fixef<-"

Tags: r, lme4

In order to run power analyses, I'd like to alter the fixed effect coefficients of my model to test power at various effect sizes.  From the primary SIMR package pub (https://besjournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/2041-210X.12504), I should be able to modify fixed effects after a model is run with the following code template:

```
fixef(model1)["x"] <- number
```

However, when I attempt to do this with my own models, I receive the following error:

```
could not find function "fixef<-"
```

If I just run `fixef(model)["x"]`, the function runs correctly.  Here is a reproducible example:

```
#Load package and data
library(lme4)
data(iris)

#build the model
mod<-lmer(Sepal.Length~Petal.Length + Petal.Width + (1|Species),
          data=iris)

fixef(mod)["Petal.Width"] #this code works
fixef(mod)["Petal.Width"] <- 1 #this code produces an error
```

If anyone knows why this is occurring, or an alternative method to modify the fixed effect coefficient values in a lmer model object, I'd be grateful to have your help with this.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] sjstats_0.18.0  lmerTest_3.1-2  lme4_1.1-23     Matrix_1.2-17   forcats_0.5.0  
 [6] stringr_1.4.0   dplyr_1.0.0     purrr_0.3.4     readr_1.3.1     tidyr_1.1.0    
[11] tibble_3.0.1    ggplot2_3.3.2   tidyverse_1.3.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] httr_1.4.1          jsonlite_1.7.0      splines_3.6.0       modelr_0.1.8       
 [5] assertthat_0.2.1    statmod_1.4.34      blob_1.2.1          cellranger_1.1.0   
 [9] yaml_2.2.1          bayestestR_0.7.0    numDeriv_2016.8-1.1 pillar_1.4.4       
[13] backports_1.1.7     lattice_0.20-38     glue_1.4.1          rvest_0.3.5        
[17] minqa_1.2.4         colorspace_1.4-1    sandwich_2.5-1      pkgconfig_2.0.3    
[21] broom_0.5.6         haven_2.3.1         xtable_1.8-4        mvtnorm_1.1-1      
[25] scales_1.1.1        emmeans_1.4.7       generics_0.0.2      sjlabelled_1.1.6   
[29] ellipsis_0.3.1      TH.data_1.0-10      withr_2.2.0         cli_2.0.2          
[33] survival_3.2-3      magrittr_1.5        crayon_1.3.4        effectsize_0.3.1   
[37] readxl_1.3.1        estimability_1.3    fs_1.4.1            fansi_0.4.1        
[41] nlme_3.1-148        MASS_7.3-51.4       xml2_1.3.2          rsconnect_0.8.16   
[45] tools_3.6.0         hms_0.5.3           lifecycle_0.2.0     multcomp_1.4-13    
[49] munsell_0.5.0       reprex_0.3.0        compiler_3.6.0      rlang_0.4.6        
[53] grid_3.6.0          nloptr_1.2.2.1      parameters_0.8.0    rstudioapi_0.11    
[57] boot_1.3-22         gtable_0.3.0        codetools_0.2-16    DBI_1.1.0          
[61] sjmisc_2.8.5        R6_2.4.1            zoo_1.8-8           lubridate_1.7.9    
[65] knitr_1.29          performance_0.4.7   insight_0.8.5       stringi_1.4.6      
[69] Rcpp_1.0.4.6        vctrs_0.3.1         dbplyr_1.4.4        tidyselect_1.1.0   
[73] xfun_0.15           coda_0.19-3
```

Thank you.

Comment: The first line of code in the tutorial is `library(simr)`.  I don't see the same in your code.  Presumably `fixef<-` is a function defined in `simr`.  If so, that would explain your problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error simply says that this function is not implemented. When you say `fixef(mod)["Petal.Width"] <- 1` you're actually doing `` `fixef<-`((mod)["Petal.Width"], 1) `` , because actually anything in R is a function.

What you can do is:

```
## before manipulation
fixef(mod)
# (Intercept) Petal.Length  Petal.Width 
#  2.51329946   0.89385535  -0.02424226 

## manipulate    
mod@beta[names(fixef(mod)) %in% "Petal.Width"] <- 1

## after manipulation
fixef(mod)
# (Intercept) Petal.Length  Petal.Width 
#   2.5132995    0.8938554    1.0000000
```

You may want to explore `str(mod)` which will reveal the logic behind this.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is another way to do this, but the reason `fixef(mod)["Petal.Width"] <- 1` produces an error above is because `fixef<-` is defined in the simr package. Installing and loading simr will allow assignment by fixef to work. It is, however, a weird way to treat a model.

Comment: Indeed. Using the hidden function `lme4:::setParams()` would be one step better ... or asking the package maintainer to export it ...